# NSString and isEqualToString with strange output

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I got a error in my app and as I tried to fix it I had a really strange behavior when I debugged my method.

Check the following code:(`testString` is an `NSString`)

```
NSLog(@"logging:AAAA%@AAAA",[testObject testString]);

if ([[testObject testString] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
    NSLog(@"yeah im here!");
}
```

and its printing:

```
logging:AAAA(null)AAAA
```

But it never reaches the "yeah im here!". How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `testString` is `nil`.

NSLog produces "(null)" when passed a `nil` object. However calling a method (like `isEqualToString`) on a nil object evaluates to `nil` again and thus to false in the "if".

Comment: thank you very much for your help, really interesting, I didn't know that. I was really confused, but I was to stupid to think about that!

Comment: see my answer, explains how NSLog works, and where the "(null)" comes from.

Answer (score 2):

NSLog always prints the description of an Object.

In fact it's NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION.

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

So:

```
NSString *stringForNSLog = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[testObject testString]];
```

the `*stringForNSLog` should exactly be "(null)".

But the value of testString is nil.

If you're looking into GNUStep, an open-source implementation of Apple's Cocoa, you'll find something like this:

all the string format things are written in `GSFormat.m`

and in `GSFormat.m`

```
size_t len;
id obj;
NSString *dsc;

obj = args_value[specs[nspecs_done].data_arg].pa_object;

if (!obj) dsc = @"(null)";
else if ([obj respondsToSelector: @selector(descriptionWithLocale:)]) dsc = [obj descriptionWithLocale: locale];
else dsc = [obj description];
```

http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSString.m

http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/GSFormat.m

Answer (score 1):

Because testString method returns nil and calling a method on nil does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` prints the literal `(null)` if your `NSString` is `nil`. Change your test to:

```
if ([[testObject testString] == nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the testObject is nil itself.

You could test:

```
if ((testObject==nil)||([[testObject testString] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])) {
    NSLog(@"yeah im here!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((testObject==nil)||([[testObject testString] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])) {
    NSLog(@"yeah im here!");
}
```